# Use of scanf with multiple arguments

Tags: c++, algorithm

```
cout<<"\n\t Please input the real and the complex part respectively :";
if(scanf("%d+i%d",&real_part,&complex_part)!=2)
{   
    if(real_part>0)
        cout<<"\n\t You have entered only the real part";
}
```

Here I want to scan a complex number.And for this the above code works fine.If we input single number it is assigned as the real part.But I want if I give only **i4** as the input it will be assigned to complex_part remaining the real part unaltered (I have already initialize both the variable). Is there any possible way to make it happen??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will suffice:

```
if(scanf("%d", &real_part) == 1) /* If scanf succeeded in reading the real part */
{
    if(scanf("+i%d", &complex_part) == 1) /* If scanf succeeded in reading the imaginary part */
    {
        printf("Real part=%d, complex part=%d\n", real_part, complex_part);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Real part=%d, complex part=%d\n", real_part, 0);
    }
}
else if(scanf("i%d", &complex_part) == 1) /* If scanf succeeded in reading the imaginary part */
{
        printf("Real part=%d, complex part=%d\n", 0, complex_part);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Function scanf will returns the number of items successfully filled. Store the return value and make a series of if statements that handle each case:

```
const int filled = scanf( ...
if( filled == 1 )
{
    //only real
}
else if( filled == 2 )
{
    //both
}
else
{
    //none, handle error
}
```